# eclipse Mars : Debug my own framework in an existing project

Tags: java, eclipse

I assume that the question was asked many times, but I couldn't find an answer which works with my current situation : 
I developed a framework in a location A
I develop now a project in a location B. This second project uses the framework.
How can I debug my project using the framework with breakpoints in this last one?
I tried :
Import the framework as existing project in the eclipse of my project, but I can't connect both.
Create Link source in the java build path of my project. This almost works, since I can automatically add imports with references to the framework. However, for any strange reason, although the import was added by eclipse, it doesn't recognize it afterwards (import cannot be resolved).

What I don't want (for process reasons) :
Generate jar from my framework with debugging information.
Many thanks

Comment: Tried cleaning the project?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I imported my framework in my new project, then when error appears, I open the class, click on the "Attach Source" Button and select the correct framework.